# Why does this piece of Rails code delete records from mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attendants, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
end


class Attendant < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope order('notification_time ASC')
    belongs_to :appointment
end
```

The function below deletes all `attendants` where `notification_time` is not between `starts` and `ends`:

```
def this_method_is_evil
    starts = Time.parse(params[:start])
    ends = Time.parse(params[:end])
    @appointments_export = []
    types = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    user_appointments = current_user.appointments.where(type: types)
    user_appointments.each do |i|
      appointment = i
      appointment.attendants = i.attendants.where('notification_time >= ? AND notification_time <= ?', starts, ends)
      @appointments_export << appointment
    end
end
```

So basically all attendants that aren't returned by `where('notification_time >= ? AND notification_time <= ?', starts, ends)` are deleted from the mysql db.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior for a `has_many` association. When setting an association to a collection of objects, the content is replaced by the value.

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

> **collection=objects**
>
> Replaces the collections content by deleting and adding objects as appropriate. If the `:through` option is true callbacks in the join models are triggered except destroy callbacks, since deletion is direct by default. You can specify `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :nullify` to override this.